# Java inheritance not recognised in reflection

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

I generally oppose extension since it creates a very strong connection between classes, which is easy to accidentally break.

However, I finally thought I'd found a reasonable case for it - I want to optionally use a compressed version of a file type in an existing system. The compressed version would be almost as quick as the uncompressed, and would have exactly the same methods available (i.e. read and write) - the only difference would be in the representation on disk. Therefore, I had the compressed version extend the uncompressed version so that either kind of file could be used, just by optionally insantiating the other type.

```
public class CompressedSpecialFile extends SpecialFile(){ ... }

if (useCompression){
    SpecialFile = new CompressedSpecialFile();
} else {
    SpecialFile = new SpecialFile();
}
```

However, at a later point in the program, we use reflection:

```
Object[] values = new Object[]{SpecialFile sf, Integer param1, String param2, ...}
Class myclass = Class.forName(algorithmName);
Class[] classes = // created by calling .getClass on each object in values
constructor = myclass.getConstructor(classes); 
Algorithm = (Algorithm) constructor.newInstance(values)
```

Which all worked fine, but now the myclass.getConstructor class throws a NoSuchMethodException since the run-time type of the SpecialFile is CompressedSpecialFile.

However, I thought that was how extension is supposed to work - since CompressedSpecialFile extends SpecialFile, any parameter accepting a SpecialFile should accept a CompressedSpecialFile. Is this an error in Java's reflection, or a failure of my understanding?

Comment: Have you implemented default and constructor with params in your class?

Comment: I don't agree with you on extensions. There are a lot of scenarios when that **strong connection** you speak of is nothing but positive (thinking about the classic `Dog` is an `Animal` example)

Comment: @Yahor10 Not sure what you mean... which class are you referring to?

Comment: @Keyser Sure, but Animal should probably be an interface. I should clarify that I think implementing Interface's is a great idea, but situations in which it's safe to extend another non-abstract class are very rare.

Comment: @Alex Ok how about `Turtle` and `TeenageMutantNinjaTurtle`.

Comment: @Keyser precisely! If the implementation details of a real Turtle have to change, that will affect the way that TeenageMutantNinjaTurtle operates - e.g. if the turtle's size changes, that might affect its ability to do awesome ninja :)

Comment: @Alex The turtle size is object-specific of course. Not some final field :D But that was indeed a bad example. Just really wanted to post it. I get your point about interfaces, I just disagree with the fact that extend-cases are rare (simpler examples needed :p).

Comment: @Keyser Well, I guess I did end up using extension... :)

Comment: @Alex Good luck with that then :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, the response to this bug report seems to indicate that this is intentional.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4301875

> We cannot make this change for compatibility reaons.  Furthermore, we
> would expect that getConstructor should behave analogously to getDeclaredMethod,
> which also requires an exact match, thus it does not make sense to change one
> without changing the other.  It would be possible to add an additional suite of
> methods that differed only in the way in which the argument types were matched,
> however.
> There are certainly cases where we might want to apply at runtime during
> reflection the same overload-resolution algorithm used statically by the
> compiler, i.e., in a debugger.  It is not difficult to implement this
> functionality with the existing API, however, so the case for adding this
> functionality to core reflection is weak.

That bug report was closed as a duplicate of the following one, which provides a bit more implementation detail:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=1b08c721077da9fffffffff1e9a6465911b4e?bug_id=4287725

> Work Around
> Users of getMethod must be precise identifying the Class passed to the argument.

> Evaluation
> The essence of this request is that the user would like for Class.getMethod
> to apply the same overloading rules as the compiler does.  I think this is
> a reasonable request, as I see a need for this arising frequently in certain
> kinds of reflective programs, such as debuggers and scripting interpreters,
> and it would be helpful to have a standard implementation so that everybody
> gets it right.  For compatibility, however, the behavior of the existing
> Class.getMethod should be left alone, and a new method defined.  There is
> a case for leaving this functionality out on the basis of footprint, as it
> can be implemented using existing APIs, albeit somewhat inefficiently.
> See also 4401287.
> Consensus appears to be that we should provide overload resolution in
> reflection.  Exactly when such functionality is provided would depend largely
> on interest and potential uses.
> For compatibility reasons, the Class.get(Declared)+{Method,Constructor}
> implementation should not change; new method should be introduced.  The
> specification for these methods does need to be modified to define "match".  See
> bug 4651775.

You can keep digging into those referenced bugs and the actual links I provided (where there's discussion as well as possible workarounds) but I think that gets at the reasoning (though why a new method reflecting java's oop in reflection as well has not yet been implemented, I don't know).

In terms of workarounds, I suppose that for the one-level-deep version of inheritance, you can just call getSuperclass() on each class whose name is that of the extending class, but that's extremely inelegant and tied to you using it only on your classes implementing in the prescribed manner.  Very kludgy.  I'll try and look for another option though.

Comment: Thanks Walker, that's very helpful. So my read on that is that there is no existing solution at the moment?

Comment: Updated with a very kludgy possible workaround.  I'll try and look for another, but no guarantees.

Comment: Fair enough. No one's expecting you to re-write the JVM :)